# Spawn chrome with --disable-web-security flag in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome

So as the question above implies I'm trying to create a chrome instance with the --disable-web-security flag, but when I run this all it does is open a new tab

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const child = execFile('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe', ['--disable-web-security', 'https://google.com']);
```

Comment: Make sure you have all chrome instances closed.

Comment: I did then I tried to make a cors ajax request and it's still blocking it

Comment: I'm on windows 10 if that helps

Comment: I think you can just use `exec` and run `chrom https://google.com --flats`

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question you need to run --disable-web-security with --user-data-dir